# Atualizar valores após alteração de dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não sei quase nada de JavaScript mas consegui usar o Chosen para mudar minhas *selects*.
O que não estou conseguindo é usar o *trigger* que o site indica para atualizar o campo.

Quero que cada vez que clique no campo select e o *dropdown list* acione, ele atualize os valores.

Sei que o site diz para colocar `$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");` mas não sei onde, também não sei o que é o `#form_field`. É o id do formulário? Do campo? Tenho que criar algum evento com `onselect` ou `onclick`?

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<title>Cadastro de Filmes</title>
</head>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.chzn-select').chosen({width: "50%", no_results_text: "Sem registro de ", size: "5"});
});
</script>

<body>

<div class='cadastro' >
 <h1>Cadastro de Filmes</h1>
 <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='form1' id='form1'>
 <p>País
    <select name='pais[]' data-placeholder=' ' multiple class='chzn-select')
      <?php
        //LAÇO PARA BUSCAR TODOS OS DADOS DO BANCO MARCANDO AQUELES QUE ESTÃO SELECIONADOS 
        $j=0;
        $tam=sizeof($pais_sel);
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($pais);$i++){
         if($pais[$i]==$pais_sel[$j]){
          echo "<option value='$pais[$i]' selected>$pais[$i]</option>";
         if($j<$tam-1){
          $j++;
         }
        }else{
          echo "<option value='$pais[$i]'>$pais[$i]</option>";
         }      
       }
       ?>
    </select>
    </p>
  <p>
    <input name='enviar' type='submit' id='enviar' value='Enviar' />
  </p>
  </form>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podes colocar o código que tens aqui?

Comment: Como coloco código aqui?

Comment: Pode [edit] a pergunta e colocar o código na pergunta. Se precisar de ajuda a formatar o código nós ajudamos.

Comment: Coloquei o código, mas nem todo apareceu.

Comment: Olá, amigos. Vou tentar ser mais claro.
Tenho um formulario de cadastro de filmes em que tem um campo país, por exemplo, para selecionar os países que co-produziram esse filme. Vou criar ao lado desse campo um botão novo para cadastrar novos países. O que preciso é que o campo país do primeiro formulário atualize com o novo país que acabei de cadastrar sem ter que dar um refresh na página, pois assim perderia os dados digitados nos outros campos. Creio que seja com a função update do chosen que estou usando, mas não sei usar direito.

Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Tem erros aqui `<select name='pais[]' data-placeholder=' ' multiple class='chzn-select');" >` tem `);"` a mais. Tem algum erro na consola?

Comment: Olá, Sergio. Já notei o erro, foi de digitação, mas o problema não está nesse código. Quero saber o que tenho que acrescentar nele para atualizar a tag select com o chosen. Abraços

Comment: Seria ideal fazer um jsFiddle com o problema. Mas vou dar uma olhada. Se puder entretanto coloque o HTML renderizado, melhor para testar.

Comment: Olá, Sergio. Desculpe, não sei usar jsFiddle. Quer que coloque capturas da página?

Comment: Pode explicar o que falta aqui: __http://jsfiddle.net/rq7fkzpk/__

Comment: Conseguiste resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso:

```
$('.chzn-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Agora,mudando de assunto

Agora seu problema em atualizar o pais, eu sugiro que você use o knockoutjs e "link" seu select a um array, após salvar o novo país via callback, volte a acrescente um ítem no array, e seu problema estará resolvido.

Comment: Ola, amigo. Não sei bem onde colocar esse código.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('.chzn-select').chosen({width: "50%", no_results_text: "Sem registro de ", size:"5"});
    $(document).on('chosen:updated', '.chzn-select', function(e,x){

       //Não sei direito o que voce quer fazer aqui,
       // Mas coloco o código aqui, ele será executado toda vez que o usuario mudar o chosen
      //De uma olhada nos parametros e, x

       alert('Alguma alteração aconteceu');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Seria melhor voce editar sua resposta original acrescentando este trecho em vez de postar 2 pedaços.

Comment: Olá, Penihel. Agradeço pela resposta.
Como disse antes não entendo nada de Java, apenas copiei o que vi num fórum para fazer funcionar o chosen. O que quero, se possível, é que se eu atualizasse o banco de dados não fosse preciso dar um refresh na página do formulário para atualizar o campo. Infelizmente não entendi seu código. Abraços

Answer (score 1):

Basta você criar uma função que atualiza o `select` Chosen, adicionando um novo `option` ao `select`. Fiz uma implementação no Fiddle do Sergio que mostra como funciona, aí basta você adaptar conforme queira: http://jsfiddle.net/rq7fkzpk/3/